# Nest JS, Mongoose: Inject service into model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I'm having a problem with Nest Js and mongoose, Im trying to make a seed for my database,
And the main problem I'm having is I cannot import service from my module, into other module.

And it constantly gives me error:

**Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CategoryModel (?). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the MongooseModule context.**

the main thing I'm trying to do is to create seed for my categories.

**Here is my Category Module:**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CategoryController } from './category.controller';
import { CategoryService } from './category.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { CategorySchema } from 'src/models/category.schema';

@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Category', schema: CategorySchema }])],
  controllers: [CategoryController],
  providers: [CategoryService]
})
export class CategoryModule {}
```

**My Category service:**

```
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CategoryInterface } from '../interfaces/category.interface';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {
  constructor(@InjectModel('Category') private categoryModel: Model<CategoryInterface>) {}

  async create(category){
    const createdQuestion = new this.categoryModel(category);

    return createdQuestion.save();
  }

  async getMainCategories() {
     return this.categoryModel.find( { parent: null } );
  }
}
```

**My Category Controller:**

```
import { Controller, Post, Get, Body, HttpCode } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CategoryService } from './category.service';

@Controller('category')
export class CategoryController {

  constructor(private categoryService: CategoryService) { }

  @Post()
  @HttpCode(204)
  async createCategory(@Body() category) {
    console.log('evo je kategorija ', category);
    const data = await this.categoryService.create(category);
  }

  @Get('/main')
  async getAllCategories() {
      const data = await this.categoryService.getMainCategories();
      return data;
  }

}
```

**My Seeder module where I'm having provider that seed database:**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Seeder } from './seeder';


@Module({
  providers: [Seeder],
})
export class SeederModule {}
```

**and my seeder.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CategoryService } from 'src/category/category.service';

@Injectable()
export class Seeder {

  constructor(private categoryService: CategoryService) { }


  async seed() {

  }
  async categories() {
   // const data = await this.categoryService.createMultiple(categories);

  }
}
```

**My App.module**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { CategoryModule } from './category/category.module';
import { QuizModule } from './quiz/quiz.module';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import config from './config/config';

@Module({
  imports: [  
              MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost:27017'),
              ConfigModule.forRoot({ load: [config], isGlobal: true }), 
              CategoryModule,
              QuizModule
            ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Category Model:

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export const CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type:String, required:true, unique: true },
  slug: { type:String, required:true, unique: true },
});
And for some reason it is not working, even If I import whole
```

**GitHub Repository of Project**: https://github.com/HunterJS-bit/react-quiz-app

CategoryModule, or CategoryService into Seeder.module ??

> Note: To reproduce error try running `npm run seed` from
>   server/package.json

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the `CategoryModule` add `exports: [CategoryService]` to allow for other modules to import the module and make use to the `CategoryService`. This is how you share providers in NestJS. The, you need to add `imports: [CategoryModule]` to the `SeederModule` to allow the providers of the `SeederModule` to use the `exports` of the `CategoryModule`. Then, everything should load up just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick response, will try it right now, but one question why do I have to import whole Category module why cannot I just import CategoryService ?

Comment: Now Im getting following error:  Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CategoryModel (?). Please make sure that the argument DatabaseConnection at index [0] is available in the MongooseModule context ?

Comment: You could "import" the `CategoryService` via adding it to the `providers` array, but then you'll need to "import" all of `CategoryService`'s dependencies too. This will also make a new instance of the `CategoryService`. By adding the `CategoryModule` you bring in the existing `CategoryService` and don't need to worry about all the dependencies again.

Comment: That new error is probably related to how the `MongooseModule` is added to your application, and without seeing the whole implementation, it won't be easy to track down.

Comment: Thanks again I have added more code in question app.module and category.schema

Comment: Thank you for your help, if you have time I was getting following error:

Comment: I'm not seeing the the updated implementation of `CategoryModule` or of `SeederModule`. If you have a GitHub repository, I'd be happy to clone it and help out.

Comment: Feel free to take a look: https://github.com/HunterJS-bit/react-quiz-app

Comment: @Loki I cloned your project, installed the dependencies and started the server. I got not errors. You may want to end up removing your `dist` directory and rebuilding the entire project

Comment: there still is, try running command `npm run seed`, from server/package.json

Comment: Got it. The issue there is when you create a new Nest context as you are doing, there is no `MongooseModule.forRoot()` that sets up the initial connection, so there's no way for Nest to know how to run the seeding. If this `SeederModule` is only going to be used for seeding the database via this `seed` command, you should add in `MongooseModule.forRoot(mongoURI)` and it will all work properly.

Comment: Great thank you so much one more question should I add that in seed.ts or I should add that in seeder.module.ts

Comment: The module file.

Comment: Wow it working, thank you so much, could I ask you one more thing... I see you are experienced with Nest JS, is this a proper way and acceptable way to seed database ?